# Page file size in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, memory, virtual-memory, paging

As I have gone through some articles, the virtual memory page file size should be 1.5 multiplied by the RAM size. I am currently using 8GB physical RAM in my laptop. So accordingly the page file should be (1024*8)*1.5 = 12,288 MB . But why is it showing 1900MB instead?

This is my virtual memory allocation:

[image: this is my virtual memory allocation]

Comment: That old rule of thumb was OK to about Windows 7. On Win10, especially if you have an SSD, just let the system handle it.

Comment: Much nonsense has been written, and much time wasted by obsessive people, over this issue. Let Windows handle it and get your life back.

Comment: I rewrote your question for clarity because there’s actually a page size, too.